# (OS X) Prevent keyobard during programmatic mouse click

Tags: macos, nsevent

I'm trying to port keynav to OS X. It is basically working, but I'm facing a problem due to the inability to change (global) monitored events.

Is it possible to suppress a keyboard modifier during a mouse click event? Maybe using a sequence, for example creating a keyboard event with "control key up" + mouse click?

This is my mouse click method:

```
- (void)clickMouseAtPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGEventRef move = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
                                               NULL, kCGEventMouseMoved,
                                               point,
                                               kCGMouseButtonLeft // ignored
                                               );

    CGEventRef click1_down = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
                                                     NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown,
                                                     point,
                                                     kCGMouseButtonLeft
                                                     );
    CGEventRef click1_up = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
                                                   NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseUp,
                                                   point,
                                                   kCGMouseButtonLeft
                                                   );

    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, move);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click1_down);
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click1_up);

    CFRelease(click1_up);
    CFRelease(click1_down);
    CFRelease(move1);
}
```

Comment: i've found  solution. modification of code from here: https://gist.github.com/boratlibre/8313195 I'll add an answer to my question later. navkey works fine now. Maybe I'l add it to github.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I ended up with. Background to what is done here in particular: The keynav is overlayed to the whole desktop when pressing ctrl+comma, a user may navigate the cross-hair using holding ctrl+SomeKeys, and simulate a mouse click at the cross-hait position by a second ctrl+comma (awaitClick is set when the second click is awaited in the code snippet below).

Now, before the click is done the control key modifier is removed from the keyboard event. Also, while keynav is shown all keyboard input is swapped with keycode -1. I found this by experimenting that this suppresses a key press.

If this is a good way or not, I can't tell. But it works reliably so far.

```
CGEventRef
myCGEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type,
                  CGEventRef event, void *refcon)
{
    if ((type != kCGEventKeyDown) && (type != kCGEventKeyUp))
        return event;

    CGKeyCode keycode = (CGKeyCode)CGEventGetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode);

    EWAppDelegate *appInstance = [NSApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    CGEventFlags flags = CGEventGetFlags(event);

    if (_awaitClick && keycode == (CGKeyCode)43 && type == kCGEventKeyDown)
    {
        flags = flags & ~kCGEventFlagMaskControl;
        CGEventSetFlags(event, flags);
        NSLog(@"suppressed control key");
    }

    BOOL didHandle = NO;

    if (type == kCGEventKeyDown)
    {
        didHandle = [appInstance handleNavKey:keycode flags:flags];
    }

    NSLog(@"pressed keycode %d", keycode);

    if (didHandle || _navIsSHowing) {
        CGEventSetIntegerValueField(event, kCGKeyboardEventKeycode, (int64_t)-1);
        NSLog(@"nav");
    }

    return event;
}

- (BOOL)registerGlobalKeyBoardModifier
{
    CFMachPortRef      eventTap;
    CGEventMask        eventMask;
    CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource;

    eventMask = ((1 << kCGEventKeyDown) | (1 << kCGEventKeyUp));
    eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, 0,
                                eventMask, myCGEventCallback, NULL);
    if (!eventTap) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create event tap\n");
        return NO;
    }

    runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(
                                                  kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);

    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource,
                       kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);

    return YES;
}
```